# Large Difference in Output: nnGraph based LSTM vs Sequencer LSTM (Torch)

Tags: torch

I have implemented a Sequence Labeler in Torch using rnn from [Element Research](https://github.com/Element-Research/rnn) and also using nnGraph based LSTM code from [Oxford ML Group](https://github.com/oxford-cs-ml-2015/practical6). The training of the nnGraph based LSTM is done similar to the one given in Oxford ML Group.

I have kep the hyperparameters same for both the modules. When i train both the modules on same dataset i get lower error(around 75 Fmeasure) on rnn from Element Research while the error is large(around 5 Fmeasure) using nnGraph based LSTM.

For simplification i do Backpropagaton Through Time over the enitire sequence on both the models. For nnGraph based LSTM I clone it for maximum length of the sequence.

Here is the snippet for training using `rnn` package:

```
------------------ forward pass -------------------
local embeddings = {}            -- input embeddings
local loss = 0
if inputSource:size(1) ~= target:size(1) then
  print("Size mismatch "..inputSource:size(1).."\t"..target:size(1))
  os.exit()
end
-- Send the input sequence through a Lookup Table to obtain it's embeddings

for t=1,inputSource:size(1) do
  if options.useGPU then
    embeddings[t] = embed:forward(inputSource[t])[1]:cuda()
  else
    embeddings[t] = embed:forward(inputSource[t])[1]
  end
end

  -- Send the embedding sequence to prduce a table of ner tags
local predictions = sequenceLabeler:forward(embeddings)
loss = loss + criterion:forward(predictions, target)
local gradOutputs = criterion:backward(predictions, target)
sequenceLabeler:backward(embeddings, gradOutputs)
loss = loss / inputSource:size(1)
```

and the snippet for training using nnGraph based LSTM is

```
local embeddings = {}            -- input embeddings
local loss = 0
if inputSource:size(1) ~= target:size(1) then
  print("Size mismatch "..inputSource:size(1).."\t"..target:size(1))
  os.exit()
end
-- Send the input sequence through a Lookup Table to obtain it's embeddings

for t=1,inputSource:size(1) do
  embeddings[t] = embed:forward(inputSource[t])[1]
end
local lstm_c = {[0]=initstate_c} -- internal cell states of LSTM
local lstm_h = {[0]=initstate_h} -- output values of LSTM
local predictions = {}           -- softmax outputs

--  For every input word pass through LSTM module and softmax module 
for t = 1, inputSource:size(1) do
  lstm_c[t], lstm_h[t] =   unpack(clones.memory[t]:forward({embeddings[t]:cuda(), lstm_c[t-1]:cuda(), lstm_h[t-1]:cuda()}))
  predictions[t] = clones.softmax[t]:forward(lstm_h[t])

  loss = loss + clones.criterion[t]:forward(predictions[t]:float(), target[t])
end

local dlstm_c = {} 
local dlstm_h = {} 
--  Gradients from higher layers are zero
dlstm_c[inputSource:size(1)]=dfinalstate_c:cuda() --Zero tensors
dlstm_h[inputSource:size(1)]=dfinalstate_h:cuda() --Sero tensors

local dTempSummary = {} -- gradient to be sent to lookup table. But remember the lookup table isn't modified
for t = inputSource:size(1),1,-1 do
  local doutput_t = clones.criterion[t]:backward(predictions[t]:float(), target[t]):clone()

  --Gradient from output layer. If the token is the last in the sequence there's no additional gradient coming down
  --Else need to consider gradient from previous tokens so add
  if t == inputSource:size(1) then
    dlstm_h[t] = clones.softmax[t]:backward(lstm_h[t], doutput_t):clone()
  else
    dlstm_h[t]:add(clones.softmax[t]:backward(lstm_h[t], doutput_t))
  end

  -- backprop through LSTM timestep
  dTempSummary[t], dlstm_c[t-1], dlstm_h[t-1] = unpack(clones.memory[t]:backward(
      {embeddings[t]:cuda(), lstm_c[t-1]:cuda(), lstm_h[t-1]:cuda()},
      {dlstm_c[t]:cuda(), dlstm_h[t]:cuda()}
  ))

end
loss = loss / inputSource:size(1)
```

I have shared the complete code snippet here : [Complete Code Snippet for both modules](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/rmurthy/rLopM/sequence-labeling-using-lstm)

I know that i'm missing something in my nnGraph based LSTM implenetation but unable to figure out my error. Can someone please help me in finding where i am wrong?